# How to Combine Two Related Functions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

**Title:** Highest Scoring Word

**Info:**
I'm having a hard time getting these two code snippets to work in just one function. Currently, the first code snippet just splits up the sentence into individual word and letter arrays. The second code snippet is what I want the first to do with each individual sentence-word-letter array.

**Question:** How can I get these two functions to work together so that they return the word with the highest index value sum.

**Return:** These functions combined will return the sum of each word in the sentence to determine which word has the highest sum value.

**Example:**
If the sentence is "aa bb" then,

"aa" < "bb" because "aa" === 2 and "bb" === 4, so this function will return the word "bb", because "aa" is less than "bb".

---

**My Attempt** (*related to info*):

**Snippet #1:**

(splits up each word for its individual word characters)

```js
//Snippet #1

function high(x){
  const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const ltrArr = x.split(" ").map((w) => {
    return w.split("")
  })
  return ltrArr
}

console.log(high('this is a test sentence')) //-- returns word/letter array
```

**Snippet #2:**

(for each of the sentences words, split each word into its individual letters and sum up the total index values)

```js
//Snippet #2

const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const firstWordLtrs = ['t','h','i','s']; //the first word of the sentence split up into a character array. 

const sum = firstWordLtrs.map((l) => { //finds the index of the individual letter in the alphabet and sums up the total.
  const index = alph.indexOf(l)+1
  return index
}).reduce((a,b) => a+b)

console.log(sum) //--returns 56
```

**Finally:** Both these functions together will return the individual index sum for each word in the sentence. (eg. return "bb" for sentence "aa bb")

*ps. I wasn't sure what to title this question.*

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not change questions as fundamentally as you did after you got answers. Ask a new questin instead, allowing the existing answers to stay valid (and collect more rewards) and keeping the usefulness of the Q/A pair. If you need to discuss something new please create a new question.

Comment: @Yunnosch the other information is completely unnecessary and only confuses the next person trying to either answer or learn from this question.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which invalidates one or more answers, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have reverted your edit. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @Makyen didn't change the question, I just rephrased it because I wasn't sure exactly what I wanted originally. Fortunately, the community assisted me so that I can formulate a better question. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I'm aware that your change makes the question more generic, yet still covering a similar underlying problem. However, the change in how you are asking, from "how do I combine these two functions" to "do this for me", results in the existing answers not really fitting the second question, which can result in the existing answers not being received as well as a new answer (i.e. not getting upvotes and/or getting downvotes). Making such changes is not fair to the users who have already answered your original question, which is why doing making such changes is against policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, but is this what you were looking for?

```js
const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

const sum = (sentence) => {
  let highest = {
    word: "",
    score: 0
  }
  sentence.split(" ").forEach(w => {
    let s = 0;
    w.split("").forEach(l => {
      s += (alph.indexOf(l) + 1);
    })
    if (s > highest.score) highest = {
      word: w,
      score: s
    };

  })
  return highest;
}

console.log(sum('this is a test sentence'))
//-- returns word/letter array
```

Comment: Works great @Kinglish! Thank you for sticking with me. I can see how the original question didn't make sense.

Comment: I made a small edit just now for performance reasons. (moved the s.highest comparison out of the forEach loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize chain methods like this.

```
const sum = high('your sentece here').map((l) => { //finds the index of the individual letter in the alphabet and sums up the total.
  const index = alph.indexOf(l)+1
  return index
}).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the nested arrays in the first function since they didn't really serve a purpose. Let me know if it was intentional.

Otherwise, this provides the combined functionality into a single function:

```js
function high(x) {
  const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  const ltrArr = x.replace(" ", "").split("")
  
  const sum = ltrArr
    .map((l) => alph.indexOf(l) + 1)
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(high('this is a test sentence')) // returns the index sum of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let findHighestWord = sentence => {
  let words = sentence.split(' ');
  
  const alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let scores = words.map(word => [...word]
    .map(char => alpha.indexOf(char) + 1)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b));
    
  let index = scores.indexOf(Math.max(...scores));
  return {word: words[index], index: index, score: scores[index]};
};

let sentence = 'this is a zzzz sentence';
console.log(findHighestWord(sentence));
```

**Previous answer (before question was updated) in case it's useful to anyone:**

The other answers seem to interpret your question as mapping a sentence to a single score. I think you're actually asking how to map the sentence to an array of scores, 1 score for each word in the sentence.

Here's how you could rearrange your 2 snippets into 2 functions and use them together:

```js
let splitSentence = sentence =>
    sentence.split(' ').map(word => [...word]);

let sumWord = word => {
  const alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  return word
      .map(char => alpha.indexOf(char) + 1)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

let sentence = 'this is a sentence';
let wordSums = splitSentence(sentence).map(sumWord);
console.log(wordSums);
```

And here's how you could combine the 2 functions into 1 function if that's what you're looking for:

```js
let splitSentenceAndSumWords = sentence => {
  let words = sentence.split(' ').map(word => [...word]);

  const alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  return words.map(word => word
    .map(char => alpha.indexOf(char) + 1)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b));
};

let sentence = 'this is a sentence';
console.log(splitSentenceAndSumWords(sentence));
```